# Can I get past image from google_streetview api in Python?

Tags: python, api, google-street-view

```
import google_streetview.api

params = [{
  'size': '600x300',
  'location': '42.340467,-71.048210',
  'heading': '151.78',
  'pitch': '-0.76',
  'key': 'your_api:key'
}]

results = google_streetview.api.results(params)

results.preview()


results.download_links('downloads')

results.save_links('links.txt')

results.save_metadata('metdata.json')
```

->
I wanna get past image such as 2014.09 street view data.
However, I can only get image from that code 2017 street view image data.
How can I get past image from that code?

Comment: Please format your code correctly so that it's more readable. We could help only then. Use Ctrl+K on the highlighted code section to format the code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get street view panoramas from the past. But there is a feature request for an epoch parameter in
[Google Public Issues Tracker](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/35826204).

You can indicate that you are affected by this issue and the +1 will show interest.